# LazyInitializationException in hashCode() method

Tags: java, hibernate

Could someone please help me with following.
There are Parent, Child and Grandchild entities. All in bidirectional OneToMany relations with each other .

Parent.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Child.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
```

Child.java

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;
    
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "grandchild", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Grandchild.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Grandchild> grandchildren = new HashSet<>();
```

Grandchild.java

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Child.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
private Child child;
```

The Child class has equals and hashCode methods which depend on grandchildren along with other fields (id is not a part of it).

There is a component with a method getFamily annotated as @Transactional which calls a CrudRepository<Parent, Long> method with the query

```
@Query("select p from Parent p join fetch p.children ch join fetch ch.grandchildren gch")
```

when executing this query the  Child's hashCode() is called. For this hashCode() call granchildren Set's value is *Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.*

The getFamily method has session. If calling a query like @Query("select p from Parent") and then
getChildren() for the resulting Collection - everything works. As well as viewing children, grandchildren Sets in debugger.

I plan to replace the Child and Grandchild Sets with corresponding Lists, as recommender for bidirectional OneToMany for performance reasons, which resolves the issue as well. However, I would really appreciate, if someone could explain, why the session is not extended to the entities methods in this case (regardless of join fetch the granchildren in the query) and if there is any better way to deal with this issue.

Comment: Lesson should be restrict hashcode and equals to the business key of the object, and don't involve any children. In many situations you can do fine using the equals and hash code provided by java.lang.Object.

Comment: @NathanHughes, equals and hash code are needed in case of those entities, for sad. Will look into the business keys approach. Thanks.